# Want to make a Read more option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Fact box where the content can vary from a `p, li or img tags`, and the content length may also vary. Therefore, I have tried to make a function that only shows a part of the content, and a button to `"read more"`.

But my problem is that when I use the substring to count where to start, and where to stop, and put the button "read more" in, but it's take both the HTML text and the plain text, but i only need the plain text.

So my question is: How do I remove all HTML text and just get plain text so it does not matter what kind of content that is in my facts box, it will still only show a portion of text, and hide the rest, with a button with option to show more. ??

My function that only show parts off the fact box:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var showChar = 100;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "Read more";
var lesstext = "less";

$('.showMoreLess').each(function () {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);
        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

});

and my HTML, and agian it may vary what it contains

```
<div class="fact-banner">
     <h4 class="title">fact headline</h4>
     <div class="showMoreLess">
          <div class="text">
                <p>blablabla</p>
                <p>blablabla</p>
                <p>blablabla</p>
                <p>blablabla</p>
          </div
          <div class="img">
                 <div class="image-banner text" style="padding-top: 0;margin-top:0">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="/bla.jpg" alt="bla" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <p>imageText</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div> 

          <div class="text" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0">
                <a href="linkToRelevantsite"> Relevant site to the article </a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

I hope i make sense :)

Comment: This one is covered really well in a previous question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

```
var content = $(this).text();
```

Comment: The problem with using .text, is that it removes my h4 and so on, and makes it all to plain text :/

Comment: Your question makes it sounds like that is the desired goal: "How do I remove all HTML text and just get plain text", can you clarify your question?

Comment: yes sorry, that I can see is a little misleading.
But I want to make a Read more option that hides some of my content in the fact box, where i still keep all of my tags.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of your question is definitely confusing.  I think what you want is `overflow:hidden;` and not actually removing tags.

Append a `.text-wrapper` to your `.text`.  `.text-wrapper` will have a fixed height when collapsed, and a height auto when expanded.  `.text-wrapper` will have `overflow: hidden`.

Here's a quick codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVZNvv